# Voltar para o inicio do código após um if ou switch case em C

Tags: c, if, switch

Estou com uma dúvida referente ao `if`.

Estou desenvolvendo um programa para o fim de semestre da faculdade e toda vez eu preciso usar um `if` e no fim do `if`, eu preciso que volte para o começo do programa. Estou tendo dificuldade em fazer isso.
Exemplo:
OBS: O código abaixo é ilustrativo, pois o meu é muito grande e não conseguirei postar aqui.

```
char op;

print("Digite algo");
scanf("%s", &op);

if (op == "nome") {

//algo aqui

}

if (op == "telefone") {

//algo aqui

}

if (op != 'nome' && op != 'telefone') {

//queria colocar algo aqui que fizesse o usuario voltar ao começo do codigo e pedir o valor da op pra ele de novo.

}
```

Essa minha dúvida também está relacionada ao `switch case`, onde no `default` eu queria colocar algo nesse estilo (De voltar para o começo do código).

Alguém pode me ajudar a entender?

Comment: Coloque o resto do código para ver onde ele tem que voltar.

Comment: Seu codigo tem problemas está a armazebar uma string num char e a vericar strings com `==` não irá funcionar. Na minha opinião, poderia usar `goto` não iria prejudicar muito a legibiliade, ou Como @bigown já disse poste o resto do código.

Comment: Ah entendi. Então, o meu código verdadeiro é muito grande, por isso não postei...Esse foi um exemplo rápido do que eu tenho dúvida. Eu deveria ter especificado isso lá em cima. :/ Vou editar. Mas obrigada mesmo assim. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Podes usar um `do-while`. Enquanto não for digitada uma opção válida o programa irá continuar a pedir um input do utilizador.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {

    char op;

    do {      
         printf("Digite algo\n  0 - Sair\n  1 - Nome\n  2 - Telefone\n");

         scanf(" %c", &op);

         switch(op) {
               case '0': //sair
                   printf("Escolheu sair do menu\n");
                   break; 
               case '1': //nome
                   printf("Escolheu opção nome\n");
                   break;
               case '2': //telefone
                   printf("Escolheu opção telefone\n");  
                   break;
               default:
                   printf("Escolheu uma opção inválida\n");
                   break;
         }
    } while (op != '0');

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ah, obrigada. Vou tentar fazer aqui com o Do-While. ;)